# trace geolocation every 30 second -Phonegap app in background or closed

Tags: phonegap-plugins

how can i trace geolocation every 30 second even app in background
i'm using navigator geolocation plugin (navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition) in app to get location.and i tried it with setinterval but plugin doesn't work when app in background process.

please someone guide me it's for android and ios for both plateform!

Comment: hello @AnujGupta  i use this   { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 30000, enableHighAccuracy: true }

it's not giving accurate interval like 30 sec

Comment: is it giving result on 5 sec ?

Comment: no !
now i change my option to {maximumAge: 0, timeout: 20000, enableHighAccuracy: true


Output is :
08-23 18:30:06 ,  08-23 18:30:47 , 08-23 18:33:27

some time it's give result in sec difference and sometime in minutes like  
it's give last result after 3 min

Comment: I will work on that again. I also raised this quesion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585556/watchposition-time-out-in-geolocation  but didn't get answer of it ,Will work on this issue on next week

Answer (score 0):

I worked on it today, Now it is  working fine even in background, I am getting response from it after 1 minute. I used setinterval()

```
 setInterval( function(){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success_loc, error_loc, opti)
    },(1000 * 60 * 1));
```

Use success_loc for Success and error_loc for showing error,opti for optional variable to show option like

```
   var opti = {
                timeout: (5 * 1000), maximumAge: (1000 * 60 * 1), enableHighAccuracy: true
                };
```